# OpenCTM import and output addon to work in recent Blender

Tags: export, add-on, import, file-format

The plugins included with the [OpenCTM compressed triangle mesh format](http://openctm.sourceforge.net/?page=download) doesn't work out of the box with Blender 2.7. Has anyone managed to modify these to make them work with the latest Blender versions?

Comment: this is too old is there a version for 2.6 at least , there have been a lot of API changes since then , and this addon needs rewriting

Comment: All I've found is this ancient version. OpenCTM hasn't really been under development at all for the last 5 years. However, it seems to be the only format out there capable of compressing triangular meshes well.

Comment: hey since I think this may take a long time , I think you should look for an intermediate format ( a middle software ) Blender<-->common_format<-->OpenCTM

Comment: Yes, that's good advice, and actually I've been doing that. However, I've been having some problems with UV mapping in the CTM files -- seams between UV islands are very obvious when rendered (see [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690459/strange-lines-seams-appearing-when-applying-texture-to-threejs-model) ). I was hoping to skip the intermediate conversion step to try and figure out the problem.